# Implementation in operators with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I want to define the  **T & operator() (int x, int y)** function   but i cant understand how to define it. 
I have this function in the **Array.h** file, so i have to define it in the Array.hpp file i think. Does anybody have any idea?

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_
#define _ARRAY_

namespace math
{

/*! The Array class implements a generic two-dimensional array of elements of type T.
 */
   template <typename T>
   class Array
   {
    protected:
     //! Flat storage of the elements of the array of type T
      T * buffer;                       
      unsigned int width,           
                   height;  
        /*  Returns a reference to the element at the zero-based position (column x, row y).
         *
         * \param x is the zero-based column index of the array.
         * \param y is the zero-based row index of the array.
         * 
         * \return a reference to the element at position (x,y)
         */
        T & operator() (int x, int y);  

      };
   } // namespace math

 #include "Array.hpp"
 #endif
```

Comment: Are you asking how to define it out of line? Or how to implement it?

Comment: @doctorlove i ask how to define it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

like this, for example.

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
protected:
  //! Flat storage of the elements of the array of type T
  T * buffer;
public:                      
  unsigned int width, height;  
  /// non-constant element access
  /// \param[in] x is the zero-based column index of the array.
  /// \param[in] y is the zero-based row index of the array. 
  /// \return a reference to the element at position (x,y)
  T & operator() (int x, int y)
  {
    return (buffer+x*height)[y];
  }
  /// constant element access
  /// \param[in] x is the zero-based column index of the array.
  /// \param[in] y is the zero-based row index of the array. 
  /// \return a const reference to the element at position (x,y)
  T const & operator() (int x, int y) const
  {
    return const_cast<Array&>(*this)(x,y); // note: re-use the above
  }
};
```